# HMMFit underlying algorithms

Tags: r, mixed-model, hidden-markov-model

After reading article ["Hidden Markov Models for Controlling False Discovery Rate in Genome-Wide Association Analysis"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22130891) by Zhi Wei I am trying to use it in my project. I am using R and I have found out that there is a special [function for fitting HMM](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RHmm/docs/HMMFit). 
However, I am not sure whether its implementation uses EM algorithm and how it copes with finding mixed model dimension.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: The Baum-Welch algorithm is used to find the unknown parameters of the HMM (answered by rcs at StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1):

The [RHmm-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHmm/index.html) has been deprecated. We use the depmixS4-package for our research and it is way better (although the learning curve is a little bit steeper due to the many options it has).

You find it here:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/index.html

You find a vignette with many of the implementations details here: 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/vignettes/depmixS4.pdf

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you mean by "it is way better"? in what aspects? @vonjd